# (AR / UI) Can't click a button of an AR Trackable Object ONLY when holding the phone horizontally

Tags: unity-game-engine

So I'm developing an app where if you scan specific pictures with your phone you get a prefab with the picture's name and a button, which when clicked sends you to a specific webpage.
Everything works fine, except for when I flip my phone to horizontal.
If flipped horizontally, the prefab will still show at the correct location, but the button will not register touch (i. e. is not clickable).

The button is nested within a canvas set to world space, so I'm actually not sure why the rotation of the phone matters at all.
The canvas has a script that sets the Main Camera as the world camera on Start, and it possesses a Graphic Raycaster, so it should not be the cause of the bug. (As well as the fact that it does work when held vertical.)

I did notice that it very rarely works, but not often enough that I could determine what causes the error.

I initially thought that since I use another canvas that uses Screen Space, the Screen Space Canvas may have "blocked" the click, but disabling it did nothing.

Again, it does work when held vertical. But I don't want to disable horizontal mode since the app has a Starting scene before the AR part and a short Information Scene after the button click which both work in horizontal, and I want to use the app in horizontal with a tablet.

Any help would be appreciated.